# Facebook iOS API publishInstall

Tags: ios, facebook

I've followed the tutorial: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/tutorials/mobile-app-ads/ for facebook ads on Android and iOS devices.
No ad campaign created yet.

When running the app on Android, the 'Last Mobile Install Reported' value on the facebook app page gets updated.
However, the same does not happen for iOS.

Here's my plist file:

```
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
<string>xxx</string>
<key>URL types</key>
<array>
    <dict>
        <key>URL Schemes</key>
        <array>
            <string>fbxxx</string>
        </array>
    </dict>
</array>
```

Here's the code:

```
- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(UIApplication *)application {

    [FBSettings setLoggingBehavior:[NSSet setWithObjects:FBLoggingBehaviorFBRequests, FBLoggingBehaviorFBURLConnections, FBLoggingBehaviorAccessTokens, FBLoggingBehaviorSessionStateTransitions, FBLoggingBehaviorPerformanceCharacteristics, nil]];
    NSDate *facebookIdPublishedDate = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"facebookIdPublishedDate"];
    if (!facebookIdPublishedDate) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSDate date] forKey:@"facebookIdPublishedDate"];
        [FBSettings publishInstall:FACEBOOK_APP_ID];
        NSLog(@"Published Install with Facebook App ID: %@", FACEBOOK_APP_ID);
    }
}
```

I can see the FBSDKLog output and it looks ok, no errors.
But still no result in the 'Last Mobile Install Reported' value...

Anything that I'm missing?

Comment: I'm having exactly the same problem, I use Ad Hoc release to test it before I release my app to Apple App Store.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the docs call for this call to happen in `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:`, but otherwise it should register an install once per device. Perhaps the ad campaign needs to be created before they will begin to register?